# Return multiple rows in a plqsl stored procedure in output parameters

Tags: plsql

I have to write a PL/SQL stored procedure to extract all rows from a selected table in a database
I have tried something like this:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE ANAGRAFICA_GET (
ID_O OUT NUMBER
NOME_O OUT VARCHAR2(25),
COGNOME_O OUT VARCHAR2(25),
DATA_NASCITA_O OUT VARCHAR2(25),
CITTA_NASCITA_O VARCHAR2(25),
GENERE_O OUT VARCHAR2(25),
OCCUPAZIONE_O OUT VARCHAR2(25)
)
AS
  CURSOR RESULTS IS
  SELECT ID,NOME,COGNOME,DATA_NASCITA,CITTA_NASCITA,GENERE,OCCUPAZIONE
  FROM TAB_ANAGRAFICA;
  ESTRAZIONE TAB_ANAGRAFICA%ROWTYPE;
  LAST_ID INT;
  FIRST_ID INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT ID
     INTO LAST_ID
     FROM TAB_ANAGRAFICA
     WHERE ROWNUM <=1
     ORDER BY ID DESC;
  SELECT ID
     INTO FIRST_ID
     FROM TAB_ANAGRAFICA
     WHERE ROWNUM <=1
     ORDER BY ID ASC;
  OPEN RESULTS;
     FOR i IN FIRST_ID .. LAST_ID LOOP
       FETCH RESULTS INTO ESTRAZIONE;
       ID_O := ESTRAZIONE.ID;
       NOME_O := ESTRAZIONE.NOME;
       COGNOME_O := ESTRAZIONE.COGNOME;
       DATA_NASCITA_O := ESTRAZIONE.DATA_NASCITA;
       CITTA_NASCITA_O := ESTRAZIONE.CITTA_NASCITA;
       GENERE_O := ESTRAZIONE.GENERE;
       OCCUPAZIONE_O := ESTRAZIONE.OCCUPAZIONE;
     END LOOP;
  CLOSE RESULTS;
END;
```

But when i run the stored procedure i just can see the last row in the output variables; instead if i try to write a dbms_outputline command in the loop when i run the procedure i can see that is able to fetch all the data.
How can i solve this problem ? How can i obtain a resulset instead of a single record in the output variables section ? 
Thanks to all
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure only gives the parameters marked as out in the declaration. What you are effectively doing is opening the cursor, looping through it, assigning to these parameters each time but only when the stored procedure has ended are these parameters passed out.

What you'd want to do is to just put the cursor as a paremeter:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ANAGRAFICA_GET (
    PASSED_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
) AS
BEGIN
        OPEN PASSED_CURSOR FOR
            SELECT X, Y, Z FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE;
END
```

Comment: This works good if i want to return all the values into a cursor... But i need to use the entire list of names , the entire list of cogmome  and so on separately i.e.
Root
  -NOME (list)
  -COGNOME (list)
 -....

Because i need to use all these list in an external environment

Comment: I think this happens because i output the variables outside the loop

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This way you are passing the cursor to your external environment. Then the external environment can loop through and access each record with all the values you need.

Comment: The outputs are only being passed at the end of the stored procedure. Not on each iteration. No external environment will ever get more then the parameters you define.

Comment: Thank you, i solved my problem. I processed the XML result string in an external environment obtaining all the needed records. Great !